# Bounty in ERC20 tokens

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, ethereumjs

What is the concept of ***"bounty"*** in ERC20 tokens?

How can this be implemented and what are the advantages of implementing bounty?

I am not able to find any document which states the concept of bounty. Any reference or example would be very helpful.